# Making third collection out of two collections and want all of fields in the third collections in MONGODB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mapreduce, robo3t

```
    var mapDevice = function(){
          var values = {
                     Device_Id: this.Device_Id,
                                Module_Id : this.Module_Id,
                                Area_Id: this.Area_Id,
                                Gas_Id: db.Reading.findOne({Gas_Id: db.Reading.Gas_Id})
                                };
                            emit(this.Device_Id, values);
                        };

                        var mapReading = function(){
                            var values = {
                                Device_Id :this.Device_Id,
                                Gas_Id :this.Gas_Id
                                Module_Id: db.Device.findOne({Module_Id: db.Device.Module_Id}),
                                Area_Id: db.Device.findOne({Area_Id: db.Device.Area_Id})    
                                };
                            emit(this.Device_Id, values);
                        };

                        var reduce = function(key, values){
                            var outs ={
                                Device_Id: null,
                                Module_Id : null,
                                Area_Id: null,
                                Gas_Id: null
                                };

                                values.forEach(function(v){
                                            if(outs.Device_Id ==null){
                                                outs.Device_Id = v.Device_Id
                                            }
                                            if(outs.Module_Id ==null){
                                                outs.Module_Id = v.Module_Id
                                            }
                                            if(outs.Area_Id==null){
                                                outs.Area_Id = v.Area_Id
                                            }
                                            if(outs.Gas_Id==null){
                                                outs.Gas_Id = v.Gas_Id
                                            }
                                        });
                                return outs;
                        };

                        db.Reading.mapReduce(mapReading,reduce,{
                                               out: { merge: "map_reduce_example" },
                                               query: { 'Concentration':{ $gt: 3 }}
                                               });
                        db.Device.mapReduce(mapDevice,reduce,{
                                               out: { merge: "map_reduce_example" }


                                               });
///////// DEVICE COLLECTION
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a89cb9b7c417b7a8fc07a91"),
    "Device_Id" : "DEEV2",
    "Module_Id" : "MOD1",
    "Area_Id" : "SUM"
}
//////////READING COLLECTION
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a893d946fa0c25613c14427"),
    "device_id" : "DEEV1",
    "Gas_Id" : "CO2",
    "Concentration" : 401
}

/////////MAP_REDUCE_EXAMPLE COLLECTION
{
    "_id" : null,
    "value" : {
        "Device_Id" : null,
        "Module_Id" : undefined,
        "Area_Id" : undefined,
        "Gas_Id" : "CO2"
    }
}
```

Been trying to merge 2 collections and make 3rd out of it using MAPREDUCE in mongodb. Want field included in the third(new) collection not only common ones but all of them. My two collections are DEVICE and READING and I want to have the collection map_reduce_example collection(which i am getting null values).

Following are the supporting screenshots to my code:

```
    [![This is ss of my "**Reading**" collection][1]][1]
    [![This is ss of my "**Device**" collection][2]][2]
    [![This is how i want my final collection to be i.e **"map_reduce_example"** collection to be][3]][3]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNkNR.png
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6sFK.png
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTqO.png
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could show an example document from each collection and what your expected document (output) for the third collection is like (i.e. given some input, show the expected output).

Comment: -chridam I have edited my post and kept screenshots for the same. Thanks

Comment: Can you please try to include the actual code in your question instead of images because code in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem. Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers. You're asking us to volunteer our time for free to solve your problem, and you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Comment: Sorry i aint used to with stack overflow and i would keep that in mind. Thank you in advance and sorry for the inconvenience:)